# Applying media query to an element

Tags: css

Trying to apply a media query to one particular div, but nothing is happening.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.rating {
        margin: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Where do you test this code? Mobile device? Desktop browser?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: chrome desktop @makshh

Comment: You won't see the effect because you use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` which means that your style will be visible only on devices with screen width greater than 320px and smaller than 480px. You can use `min-width` and `max-width` instead and it will work similarly but for screen size, not device size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you already missed a `}` after `.rating`

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.rating {
        margin: auto;
  }
} /* <-- this one you missed */`enter code here`
</style>
```

Also if its not device you can try to change `min-device-width` to `min-width` same for max-width.

also check the device resolution accordingly and don't forgot to add `meta` tag